# Centering a responsive image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, w3c-validation

On a page, I have an image that I want centered on the screen (horizontally).

It's responsive, so that it resizes as the screen gets too small.

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="~/Content/Images/marketing/combined-displays.png" />
```

I was using  around it, but W3C gets cross with this, and wants me to use styles instead.

So, I read up, and found this to try center images:

```
P.blocktext {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 6em
}
```

I then change the

to this:

```
<p class="blocktext">
    <img....>
</p>
```

But then the image goes tiny, in the middle of the screen.

So I removed the width, but then it doesn't centre at all.

How can I make this class center my image in the middle of the screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could change the `display` type of the image to `block` and align it to the center by `margin: 0 auto` declaration.

Besides, Twitter bootstrap has a built-in class called [`.center-block`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.css#L5639-L5643) that exactly do the same:

**[Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/9LFKV/40/)**

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" class="img-responsive center-block">
```

And `.img-responsive` would handle the rest:

```css
.img-responsive { /* Taken from Twitter bootstrap source */
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple css solution is

```
img {
      display:block;
      margin:0 auto;
      max-width:100%;
    }
```

max-width:100%; makes sure that the img isnt wider than the parent